# Single bitmap taking enormous amounts of memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I know this topic has been discussed so many times and I have read so many articles on handling large bitmap but if we put that problem aside, I would like to know why does a single bitmap take so much memory. Now, I am developing an Android application with a dynamic background. The background is gradient-like image and it's supposed to go from white, over gray to black color. I have 4  background images which together make the wanted gradient. Now, if I use only one image and make the background static, everything works perfectly fine on a device with VM heap of 64 Mb. If, however, i decided to use all backgrounds, i get outofmemory error even on a device with VM heap of 128 Mb. Now, of course, I can understand why that happens if i load all 4 images but I edited my code so that only 2 images are loaded in the memory at one moment ( if one background image is no longer on the screen, it is recycled) and that works, but barely. If i add just a single other image, which has negligible dimensions compared to the background image, it get the same error.

Another problem in all of this is that I have to scale my bitmaps after loading them. I scale them to the size of the screen. I know scaling takes up a lot of memory too, but if i do the calculations, a bitmap of dimensions 1280x720 stored as ARGB888 should use no more than 4 MB of memory.

Setting largeHeap to true won't do any help either, as some devices have heap as low as 16 MB ..

Even caching bitmaps to storage won't help because at a single moment i need more bitmaps than some devices could handle..

Also, loading sampled image won't do any help since images aren't very large (1000x1000 for xxhdpi 
density)

Code for BitmapDrawing:

```
private void DrawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
  //temp and bgs[1] are loaded at start up, as they are required right away
         if (bg_num > 3) {
         canvas.drawBitmap(bgs[3], 0, 0, null);

         if (!bgs[0].isRecycled())
         bgs[0].recycle();
         return;
         }

         if (bgs[0] == null) {
         bgs[0] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, getWidth(), getHeight(),
         false);
         temp.recycle();
         bgs_resized[0] = true;
         }

         if (bg_num == 2 && !bgs[0].isRecycled()) {
         bgs[0].recycle();

         bgs[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
         R.drawable.bg3, bitmapOptions);
         }

         if (bg_num == 3 && !bgs[1].isRecycled()) {
         bgs[1].recycle();
         bgs[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
         R.drawable.bg4, bitmapOptions);
         }

         if (!bgs_resized[bg_num]) {

         temp = bgs[bg_num];
         bgs[bg_num] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, getWidth(),
         getHeight(), false);
         bgs_resized[bg_num] = true;
         temp.recycle();
         }

         if (bg_pos < getHeight()) {
         canvas.drawBitmap(bgs[bg_num], 0, (bg_pos += BG_TRANSITION_SPEED)
         - getHeight() + 2, null);
         canvas.drawBitmap(bgs[bg_num - 1], 0, bg_pos, null);

         } else {
         canvas.drawBitmap(bgs[bg_num], 0, 0, null);
         ++bg_num;

         bg_pos = 0;

         }

    }
```

Am i doing something wrong or do i need to turn to NDK  for my solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Youre most probably doing something wrong. Show us your code and maybe someone can help.

Comment: Why is my question marked as off-topic. All that application does it draw the background.. And problem is clearly stated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you kind of answered your own question you reserve memory when you use a bitmap equal to your resolutions x 4 bytes. So this gets out of hand really quickly.
a couple of tips are.

1) use a bitmap factory that decodes your bitmap to the necessary size. for example if an imageview needs only 512x384 you don't want to load the bigger resolution bitmap in memory.

you can do it like this:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

2) make sure when you load a bitmap from disk that you do it on a different thread then the UI.

3) you should try to call recycle as soon as possible on your bitmap to free up memory (when you don't need it anymore)

4) following the previous tip. try to cache your bitmaps to increase responsiveness

```
Set<SoftReference<Bitmap>> mReusableBitmaps;
private LruCache<String, BitmapDrawable> mMemoryCache;

// If you're running on Honeycomb or newer, create a
// synchronized HashSet of references to reusable bitmaps.
if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
    mReusableBitmaps =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<SoftReference<Bitmap>>());
}

mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, BitmapDrawable>(mCacheParams.memCacheSize) {

    // Notify the removed entry that is no longer being cached.
    @Override
    protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key,
            BitmapDrawable oldValue, BitmapDrawable newValue) {
        if (RecyclingBitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(oldValue)) {
            // The removed entry is a recycling drawable, so notify it
            // that it has been removed from the memory cache.
            ((RecyclingBitmapDrawable) oldValue).setIsCached(false);
        } else {
            // The removed entry is a standard BitmapDrawable.
            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                // We're running on Honeycomb or later, so add the bitmap
                // to a SoftReference set for possible use with inBitmap later.
                mReusableBitmaps.add
                        (new SoftReference<Bitmap>(oldValue.getBitmap()));
            }
        }
    }
....
}
```